# Scrolling physics on d3 drag on graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

Not sure if this is possible, but thought I'd take a stab and see if anyone knows. I have the following code in which I'm using for dragging left and right on a d3 graph:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 1])
    .x(xscale)
    zoom.on('zoom', function() {
        var t = zoom.translate(),
        tx = t[0],
        ty = t[1];

        tx = Math.min(tx, 0);
        tx = Math.max(tx, width - max);
        zoom.translate([tx, ty]);
       svg.select('.data').attr('d', line);
});

svg.call(zoom);
```

(using from here: http://computationallyendowed.com/blog/2013/01/21/bounded-panning-in-d3.html) This works great and as expected.

My question is: does anyone know if its possible to add mobile-like gravity/physics scrolling to this pan effect? I'm building a mobile app in HTM, CSS, and JS and would like as much of a native feel as possible. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Useful and interesting question. I would like to know answer too.